# Case sensitivity in typed dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have created a typed dataset with various tables. In one of the tables, I have a column of type string. I have constrained the column to unique values. I begin adding rows to the table, and enter the value "DeWitt", then later in the process I attempt to enter the value "Dewitt". This throws a constraint violation and refuses to insert the row.

I have tried changing the dataset's CaseSensitive property (and thereby the same property on the tables). But this does not appear to have any effect.

As the two strings are different, I would expect them to not violate a unique constraint. Is there something I am doing incorrectly here?

Here is a simple test case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Test" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Test.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections />
        <Tables />
        <Sources />
      </DataSource>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Test" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:EnableTableAdapterManager="true" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="Test" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="Test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="TestTable" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="TestTableDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableTestTable" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="TestTable" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="TestTableRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="TestTableRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="TestTableRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="TestTableRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="TestTable" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="TestTableRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="TestTableRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="TestTableRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="TestColumn" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnTestColumn" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="TestColumn" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="TestColumnColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="TestColumn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:TestTable" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:TestColumn" />
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the associated code

```
using static DataSetTest.Test;

namespace DataSetTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.TestTable.AddTestTableRow("DeWitt");
            t.TestTable.AddTestTableRow("Dewitt");
            t.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Executing Init() fails on the second AddTestTableRow with the error "Column 'TestColumn' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'Dewitt' is already present."

Comment: can you show a sample code on what you have done?

Comment: `Is there something I am doing incorrectly here?` Yes. You have not showing any code you've tried.

Comment: Your described procedure sounds correct, but it would be beneficiary if you posted the dataset definition. In the Solution Explorer window, right-click on the DataSetName.xsd file and select open-with.  Then select the "Xml (Text) Editor" option; please post that xml in your question so that we can review it.

Comment: The code you have posted will create a case-insensitive dataset.  Please confirm that you still receive the error if you add `t.CaseSensitive = true;` before the adding the rows.  If you still receive the error after making the dataset case-sensitive , the only other thing that I can think of is that the current culture string comparison is causing the issue.  Please report the result of `Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);`.

Comment: Okay, I guess it's just me not paying attention to details. I thought I had set the dataset to case sensitive in the designer, but I went back and looked and it was false. Once I toggled the dataset CaseSensitive to true, things appear to be working as I expect.